# Dataproc PySpark Workers Have no Permission to Use gsutil

Tags: pyspark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, gsutil, google-cloud-datalab

Under Dataproc I setup a PySpark cluster with 1 Master Node and 2 Workers. In bucket I have directories of sub-directories of files.

In the Datalab notebook I run

```
import subprocess
all_parent_direcotry = subprocess.Popen("gsutil ls gs://parent-directories ",shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
```

This gives me all the sub-directories with no problem.

Then I hope to `gsutil ls` all the files in the sub-directories, so in master node I got:

```
def get_sub_dir(path):
    import subprocess
    p = subprocess.Popen("gsutil ls gs://parent-directories/" + path, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    return p.stdout.read(), p.stderr.read()
```

and run `get_sub_dir(sub-directory)`, this gives all files with no problem.

However,

```
 sub_dir = sc.parallelize([sub-directory])
 sub_dir.map(get_sub_dir).collect()
```

gives me:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/gsutil.py", line 99, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/gsutil.py", line 30, in main
    project, account = bootstrapping.GetActiveProjectAndAccount()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 205, in GetActiveProjectAndAccount
    project_name = properties.VALUES.core.project.Get(validate=False)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/properties.py", line 1373, in Get
    required)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/properties.py", line 1661, in _GetProperty
    value = _GetPropertyWithoutDefault(prop, properties_file)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/properties.py", line 1699, in _GetPropertyWithoutDefault
    value = callback()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/credentials/store.py", line 222, in GetProject
    return c_gce.Metadata().Project()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/credentials/gce.py", line 203, in Metadata
    _metadata_lock.lock(function=_CreateMetadata, argument=None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/mutex.py", line 44, in lock
    function(argument)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/credentials/gce.py", line 202, in _CreateMetadata
    _metadata = _GCEMetadata()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/credentials/gce.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.connected = gce_cache.GetOnGCE()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/credentials/gce_cache.py", line 141, in GetOnGCE
    return _SINGLETON_ON_GCE_CACHE.GetOnGCE(check_age)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/credentials/gce_cache.py", line 81, in GetOnGCE
    self._WriteDisk(on_gce)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/credentials/gce_cache.py", line 113, in _WriteDisk
    with files.OpenForWritingPrivate(gce_cache_path) as gcecache_file:
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/files.py", line 715, in OpenForWritingPrivate
    MakeDir(full_parent_dir_path, mode=0700)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/files.py", line 115, in MakeDir
    (u'Please verify that you have permissions to write to the parent '
googlecloudsdk.core.util.files.Error: Could not create directory [/home/.config/gcloud]: Permission denied.

Please verify that you have permissions to write to the parent directory.
```

After checking, on the worker nodes with `whoami`, it shows `yarn`.

So the question is, how to authorize `yarn` to use `gsutil`, or is there any other ways to access bucket from the Dataproc PySpark Worker nodes?

Comment: Was it just a typo in your SO question that you wrote `gcloud ls gs://` in your `get_sub_dir` function instead of `gsutil ls gs://`?

Comment: Thx, it's a typo and updated. The question remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CLI looks at the current homedir for a location to place a cached credential file when it fetches a token from the metadata service. The relevant code in `googlecloudsdk/core/config.py` looks like this:

```
def _GetGlobalConfigDir():
  """Returns the path to the user's global config area.

  Returns:
    str: The path to the user's global config area.
  """
  # Name of the directory that roots a cloud SDK workspace.
  global_config_dir = encoding.GetEncodedValue(os.environ, CLOUDSDK_CONFIG)
  if global_config_dir:
    return global_config_dir
  if platforms.OperatingSystem.Current() != platforms.OperatingSystem.WINDOWS:
    return os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), '.config',
                        _CLOUDSDK_GLOBAL_CONFIG_DIR_NAME)
```

For things running in YARN containers, despite being run as user `yarn`, where if you just run `sudo su yarn` you'll see `~` resolve to `/var/lib/hadoop-yarn` on a Dataproc node, YARN actually propagates `yarn.nodemanager.user-home-dir` as the container's homedir, and this defaults to `/home/`. For this reason, even though you can `sudo -u yarn gsutil ...`, it doesn't behave the same way as gsutil in a YARN container, and naturally, only `root` is able to create directories in the base `/home/` directory.

Long story short, you have two options:

1. In your code, add `HOME=/var/lib/hadoop-yarn` right before your `gsutil` statement.

Example:

```
   p = subprocess.Popen("HOME=/var/lib/hadoop-yarn gsutil ls gs://parent-directories/" + path, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

2. When creating a cluster, specify the YARN properties.

Example:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create --properties yarn:yarn.nodemanager.user-home-dir=/var/lib/hadoop-yarn ...
```

For an existing cluster, you could also manually add the config to `/etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml` on all your workers and then reboot the worker machines (or just run `sudo systemctl restart hadoop-yarn-nodemanager.service`) but that can be a hassle to manually run on all worker nodes.